# Sending PEC email with mailkit dotnet library (c# code)

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

Is it possible to send a pec email (italian legal email) with the MailKit library?

I did not find any examples on the net even on the site related to the library in question.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Through the power of googling, I found this, which answers your question:

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/563

While MailKit does not directly support this, it provides all the fundamentals to implement the behaviour.

Comment: I had already seen this tread, but it does not solve my problem because there is no example of code.

Comment: Having used MailKit and MimeKit in the past, I assure you there's a plethora of examples on creating messages from scratch, with custom headers and content.

Comment: can you get me a link in which you highlight the sending of a Pec? Thank you very much.

Comment: I did. All the information you need is in the RFC and the MailKit documentation. It's not directly implemented, but everything you need is there.